# How to read file from child module path where class is located

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project which contains a parent and two child modules.

**parent module directory:** C:\Users\dzata\eclipse-workspace\interfaces-qa-automation-root\

**utility module directory:**  C:\Users\dzata\eclipse-workspace\interfaces-qa-automation-root\utility

**qa-automation-inbound-event-rest module directory:**  C:\Users\dzata\eclipse-workspace\qa-automation-inbound-event-rest

In the qa-automation-inbound-event-rest module I am writing some integration tests. And in the utility module  I have some classes for connecting to databases and other stuff. For example, I have a class called Oauth2Generator which reads from a input file and then sets some properties. In that class I specified the path to be in src/main/resources/oauth2Credentials.properties.

**Problem:** I am trying to run my integration tests by cd into C:\Users\dzata\eclipse-workspace\qa-automation-inbound-event-rest and running mvn clean package. The problem is that I get an error saying that oauth2Credentials.properties is not found. After doing some digging I see that the reason is because since I am inside the  qa-automation-inbound-event-rest module,  is looking for src/main/resources inside
qa-automation-inbound-event-rest instead of the one in utility.

**Question:** How can I make sure the class Oauth2Generator inside utility module always looks for the input file inside src/main/resources inside utility instead of the other module. Even if I am running my test from qa-automation-inbound-event-rest.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: @maksimov At first I tried like this:                                                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
Properties prop  = new Properties();
prop.load(fis);

Comment: @maksimov I have also tried using Oauth2Generator.class.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/oauth2Credentials.properties")   but no luck

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources` after building your project. Resources in the JAR usually reside at the top level.

Comment: What @JFabianMeier said. Try `getResourceAsStream("oauth2Credentials.properties")`